# Can't load images from relative path with Vue V-Lazy-Image Plugin

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, vue-cli

I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-lazy-image) to create a portfolio gallery on a single page components application but I'm stuck loading the images from a relative path, it works fine if I use a full URL path.

When I use the full URL the image Loads and loose the blur as expected, instead when I use a relative path the image load but it keeps blurred and it doesn't load the class .v-lazy-image-loaded into the image tag. Any Ideas? here is the code.

LazyImage.vue

```
<template>
<v-lazy-image :src="src" />
</template>

<script>
import VLazyImage from 'v-lazy-image'

export default {
  props: {
    // HERE I TRIED TO USE A FUNCTION ALSO WITH NO LUCK
    // src: Function 
    src: String
  },
  components: {
    VLazyImage
  },
// UPDATE: I added a method to test here.
methods: {
  consoleSuccess (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Portfolio.vue

```
<template>
<section id="portfolio">
// I'M TRYING THIS TWO OPTIONS
// UPDATED: I Added here the events calls and its just calling the intersect but the load.
<v-lazy-image src="../assets/img/innovation.jpg" alt="alternate text" @load="consoleSuccess('LOADED!')" @intersect="consoleSuccess('INTERSECS!')"></v-lazy-image> <-- this just work with full url ex. http://cdn...
<v-lazy-image :src="require('../assets/img/innovation.jpg')" alt="alternate text"></v-lazy-image> <-- this loads the image but remains blured
</section>
</template>

<script>
import VLazyImage from '@/components/lazyImage'

export default {
  components: {
    VLazyImage
  }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE** 
I added a method to test and realized that just the @intersect event it's called and the @load won't fire at all with relative paths.

Comment: try to move your image file to /static and modify your path

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, I'll try some other options later this week, I am thinking if it can be something relate to the proxy... I'll give it a try too, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this was caused by bug in the component code:

`if (this.$el.src === this.src) {`

should be replaced by

`if (this.$el.getAttribute('src') === this.src) {`

I've sent pull request for this.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I had to update the min.js file also while the pull request get merged this will do it.

Comment: commit was merged, so this is now solved in main repository.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll upgrade the module ASAP